# Rails Minimagick not showing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minimagick

Why is alert not showing when submiting a form? Im trying to process images with Minimagick and validate image dimensions.

**Model**

```
`def validate_minimum_image_size
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(photo.path)
  unless image[:width] > 1300 && image[:height] > 1300
  errors.add :image, alert: "My error here"
  end
 end`
```

THANKS

Comment: Can you please show us where this method is called from?

Comment: It's just a validates:

 validate :validate_minimum_image_size

Comment: Still don't know how to handle this.